# How to determine by the wording of a test question which direction "minimal" is for divisibility order.

Tags: number-theory, order-theory

I am studying for the math subject GRE.

I have a book that gave the order "s is a multiple of t" and the set {2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9}, and asked for the minimal elements.

The answer given is 6, 8, and 9.

I would have said 2 and 3, and everything I have found online seems to be in agreement.

Is the use of the word "multiple" what flips the direction?

If so, I would think that since saying something is multiple of something else is equivalent to using the word "divisor" with the "something"'s flipped and due to the arbitrariness of "s" and "t", using the word multiple should not be sufficient to flip the direction of minimality.  And if so, can someone please explain how one is to know what it is explicitly about this wording that makes it that makes the direction certain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what your book is saying is that for $s, t \in \{2,3,4,6,8,9\}$, $s \leq t$ iff $s$ is a multiple of $t$. So for example, here $6<3$ since 6 is a multiple of 3. Thus since there are no multiples of 6, 8, or 9 in your set, there is nothing that is "less" than them, so they are minimal. On the other hand, $6<2$ since 6 is a multiple of 2, so 2 is not minimal, and so on.

Generally, orders are defined where the first variable given is less than the second based on whatever rule follows. So if a problem gives an order "$s$ is a multiple of $t$", then it means $s\leq t$ if $s$ is a multiple of $t$". If it gives an order "$z$ divides $k$", then it means $z\leq k$ if $z$ divides $k$.

Comment: I understand the order.  I need to know how was I supposed to know that direction was intended before seeing the answer.

Comment: In my experience, the alternate situation you're talking about would have been described as "s divides t". In other words, I would have inferred it from the order of the variables that we were defining s<t if s is a multiple of t rather than t<s if s is a multiple of t. I would agree that it would be best if the problem were more explicit in its definition of the order.

Comment: Okay, so alphabetic order of the variables matters (by convention), right?  That straightens my issue in my last paragraph, right?  Can you edit this (lexical) semantics part into your answer, so I can check your answer as official?

Comment: It's not about alphabetic order; rather about the order in which the variables are given. I've edited my answer- hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks!  *extra characters

Comment: I would change $<$ into $\leq$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Reading carefully the text seems to suggest the following interpretation:
$x\leq y\Leftrightarrow$ $x$ is a multiple of $y$. The given relation is simply $\mid^{op}$ (the opposite of the divisibility).

Comment: What is it that suggests that interpretation.  I know what the intended relation is due the given answer.  The question is, how was I supposed to know that direction was intended before seeing the answer.

Comment: The fact that is common to denote an order by $\leq$ instead of $\geq$. Apply this (untold) convention to the definition you read from the book

Comment: @user3146 I agree that the problem is poorly worded and ambiguous. It is fairly common but **not** universal to denote an order by $\le$ instead of $\ge.$

Comment: @Tancredi are your order symbols relative to variable first spoken of coming before the symbol and the latter coming after?  And, if so, is this a more widely understood convention than the alphabetic order suggest by emma, or more likely (I imagine) are they both used pretty widely?

Comment: I think @emma is not talking about alphabet. However I almost always found this implicit assumption, if I would use the opposite I felt absolutely guilty not to emphatize my choice. (pretty) Obviously this psychologic choice come from the very common tendence to write from left to right, so to imagine things growing towards the right-hand side.

Comment: @Tancredi Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)